# Where to buy Absinthe

Tags: spirits, absinthe, canada

I have heard a lot about this legendary beverage and I know it was forbidden in the market for a while because of some rumors, anyway, I want to give it a try but I have never seen it in any store.
It is still available on the market?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I'm in Colombia right now, but is very likely that I'll move to Canada very soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Canada you are able to purchase absinthe in most liquor stores including government run liquor stores.

Here in British Columbia, I have never seen a liquor outlet without absinthe for sale. They are usually imported from various countries such as the Czech Republic and France.

Canada also produces some of its’ own absinthe as is seen [here](https://okanaganspirits.com/products/absinthe/taboo-genuine-absinthe/).

> Liquor laws in Canada differ in the provinces, with no blanket national regulations. As of this writing, there is no law that bans or outlaws absinthe in Canada, but like in the United States, there are laws governing the amount of the psychoactive chemical thujone, which is present in absinthe.
>
> British Columbia has no regulation for thujone content, essentially legalizing absinthe in any form there. The provinces of Ontario, Alberta, and Nova Scotia allow the sale of absinthe with a thujone content of about 10 milligrams per kilogram. The remaining Canadian provinces do not allow the sale of absinthe containing thujone.
>
> As the laws governing thujone content in Canada vary by province, the laws are subject to change. - [Absinthe Laws](https://www.absinthe101.com/laws.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I buy from here: https://www.absinthes.com/

Plenty of choice and they ship worldwide.

Answer (score 1):

Just wait until you are in Canada...

E.g.

- https://okanaganspirits.com/products/absinthe/taboo-genuine-absinthe/
- https://nationalpost.com/appetizer/happy-hours-guide-to-absinthe-the-louche-bag-brands-available-in-canada

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

You can find Swiss Absinthe in Alberta - the brand is Larusee